# Hive tez execution error

Tags: hive, apache-tez

I am running a hive query and I got the following error when setting the hive.execution.engine=tez, while the query is working under engine=MR.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
```

My query is an inner join and the data is quite big.

Another thing is that I have met this problem before. But tez works later so I thought it was about something unstable about hive.

Comment: I thought your question title was meant to be "Have this execution error". Was going to edit it , then realized the tags :D

Comment: The title is meant to be Hive execution error with setting execution engine as tez.

Answer (score 2):

While running your HQL via hive include following parameter. This will give you detailed logs and you can determine the root cause easily.

```
-hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

I faced similar problem and above property help me big time.

e.g.: I got following message

```
16/04/14 10:29:26 ERROR exec.Task: Failed to execute tez graph.
org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, requested memory < 0, or requested memory > max configured, requestedMemory=20480, maxMemory=11288
```

When I changed my setting to `11288`, my query went through fine.

Answer (score 0):

Once check your **yarn-site.xml** with following properties.

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>Whether virtual memory limits will be enforced for containers</description>
  </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>4</value>
    <description>Ratio between virtual memory to physical memory when setting memory limits for containers</description>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [this post](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2019/04/28/queries-failing-via-beeline-due-to-anonymous-user/), which made it work for me. Needed to add the username

> hadoop