# Hive query failed on Tez DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, beeline, tez

I have a basic setup of Ambari 2.5.3 and HDP 2.6.3 and tried to run some simple queries below. I don't understand why it failed. Can you help?

```
[root@demo demo]# beeline
Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.6.3.0-235 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default hive hive
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.6.3.0-235)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1000.2.6.3.0-235)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> create table test2 (id int, desc varchar(40));
No rows affected (1.216 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default> insert into table test2 values (1,"aa"),(2,"bb");
INFO  : Tez session hasn't been created yet. Opening session
INFO  : Dag name: insert into table test2 ...(1,"aa"),(2,"bb")(Stage-1)
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1514250829950_0001_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1514250829950_0001_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: values__tmp__table__1 initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1514250829950_0001_1_00 [Map 1], java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getBlockIndex(FileInputFormat.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplitHostsAndCachedHosts(FileInputFormat.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:155)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]
ERROR : DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1514250829950_0001_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1514250829950_0001_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: values__tmp__table__1 initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1514250829950_0001_1_00 [Map 1], java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getBlockIndex(FileInputFormat.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplitHostsAndCachedHosts(FileInputFormat.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:155)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:266)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:0 (state=08S01,code=2)
```

**UPDATE 1**

This is what I have in Hive config

[image]

Comment: Try my answer in the following link to see more detailed log message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36630460/2421561

Comment: @Ambrish I enabled DEBUG and saw the same error msg on FileInputFormat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced the same issue, just change the execution engine to MR and it will work.

Comment: Changing to MR works but I might not have the authority to do that in our production cluster. Other Admins may give me a hard time so I need to tell them what to fix in TEZ. What's your suggestion?

Comment: I have done some R&D for the same problem but didn't get the root cause, it is related to heap memory  of TEZ . you can increase the memory of TEZ by changing some property but if the table is large, then it will again show the error.

Comment: @HP you don't need to get the admins to change it, even if they would it would be a bad idea. Just change it for your query `set hive.execution.engine=mr;`

Answer (score 0):

NPE could be related to mapred.FileInputFormat. The inputformat name matters. 
Try setting org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat for hive.input.format.

set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;