# Cannot do COUNT(*) queries from Database Console in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, hive, datagrip

I'm using IntelliJ's "Database console" feature to connect to an Apache Hive Db. It connects fine, and usually most `select` statements work fine. However, any kind of aggregate statements such as a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable...` returns the following error:

> [08S01][1] org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask

I am able to run this in Datagrip just fine, but I use the CE edition of this. I really don't want to pay for premium of Datagrip when the same feature should work in the same premium version of IntelliJ. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are there any other warning/errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: Seems like partition pruning issue..

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ Ultimate?

Comment: @moscas Yes I am using ultimate.

Comment: @y.bedrov - no other errors

Comment: @Ambrish - can you elaborate? I have the free version of Datagrip, and this runs fine there.

Comment: I would recommend to enable DEBUG mode while running the query. Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36630460/2421561

Comment: Do you use the same driver in IDEA and Datagrip? Do you use the same IDE versions (e.g. 2019.2.3)?

Comment: @y.bedrov IntelliJ is 2019.2.3 whereas Datagrip is 2019.2.2, but I had IntelliJ at 2019.2.2 and it was having the same issue. They are both using the same default "Apache Hive" driver in the configuration.

Comment: @Ambrish How do you run the Debug line from your linked answer in the IntelliJ console?

Comment: Please open "Datasources and Drivers -> Drivers -> Apache Hive" and check that the same version is used.

Comment: @y.bedrov Both are using Apache Hive driver 3.1.1

Comment: That's strange as both IDEs use the same core. Is it possibel to attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") from both IDE after restarting and reproducing the issue?